# Mysql:Trim all fields in database

Tags: mysql, trim

```
UPDATE mytable SET mycolumn= LTRIM(RTRIM(mycolumn));
```

works fine on trimming columns removing trailer spaces, but how can i adjust it to trim all columns **without having to write each column name** in table ?? cause i kind have a huge database.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some years late, but might help others:
This code trims **all** fields of a the table `your_table`.
Could be expanded to work on the whole database in the same way....

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
SELECT concat('update your_table set ',
    group_concat(concat('`',COLUMN_NAME, '` = trim(`',COLUMN_NAME,'`)')),';')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'your_table'
INTO @trimcmd;
    
PREPARE s1 from @trimcmd;
EXECUTE s1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE s1;
```

Comment: Care to share the expansion for an entire database?

Comment: It didn't work for me. It gave the error "Unexpected ordering of clauses near FROM".

Comment: Thanks this work perfectly. I have massive columns import from csv and their data is really annoying and this save my time. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

you expand the query for each column:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET mycolumn = LTRIM(RTRIM(mycolumn)),
    mycolumn2 = LTRIM(RTRIM(mycolumn2)),
    ...;
```

Comment: OP says he doesn't want to have write every column name.

Answer (score 7):

Since the question asks for the whole database, here is the script that generates the required SQL. I skip the auto execute, execute it as you like.

```
-- Set your database name here
SET @my_database:='YOUR_DB_NAME';

SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;

SELECT 
    CONCAT('UPDATE `', @my_database, '`.`', TABLE_NAME, 
            '` SET ', GROUP_CONCAT(
                CONCAT('`', COLUMN_NAME, '` = TRIM(`', COLUMN_NAME, '`)')
                ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION ASC),
            ';') AS `query`
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
    TABLE_SCHEMA = @my_database
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME ASC;
```

@ZweiStein Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
UPDATE mytable SET 
mycolumn = LTRIM(RTRIM(mycolumn)), 
mycolumn2 = LTRIM(RTRIM(mycolumn2))
```

and so on, and so forth.

Comment: Why not just TRIM()?

Comment: @GracefulCode good question...looking back, this doesn't actually address the current state of the question, i looks like it was edited after the answer was submitted.

Comment: T-SQL doesn't have `TRIM()`.  In that scenario, the `LTRIM(RTRIM(mycolumn))` trick works.

Answer (score 1):

If there are not too many columns, you could just
directly 
`UPDATE` each by your_column_name, via the `TRIM()` function:

```
UPDATE mytable SET 
mycolumn1 = TRIM(mycolumn1), 
mycolumn2 = TRIM(mycolumn2),
mycolumn3 = TRIM(mycolumn3),
mycolumn4 = TRIM(mycolumn4)
```

Otherwise, [ZweiStein's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28275037/5411817) answer above for a single **table**,
or [Izhar Aazmi's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37565653/5411817) answer for an entire **database**  seem the way to go.

[Hiram's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22261620/5411817) answer to  another SO Post includes a check to *only TRIM* **VARCHAR** fields: excellent feature!

Or, if using T-SQL, or others which do not support `TRIM`,  use the `LTRIM(RTRIM(...))` trick,
 suggested by [Jim Rubenstein](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6072331/5411817) and [Denis de Bernardy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6072254/5411817) above.

Answer (score 0):

I was actually looking for something similar for a legacy table that's constantly updated by an outside source when I came across this question. I realize the OP was looking for a purely SQL(MySQL) answer, but in case you use Rails, you might find this tidbit that I came up with helpful:

```
MyModel.update_all(MyModel.columns.map(&:name).map{|x| "#{x} = TRIM(#{x})"}.join(', '))
```

You can also wrap it into a class method in your model

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.trim_all
   update_all(columns.map(&:name).map{|x| "#{x} = TRIM(#{x})"}.join(', '))
 end
end
```

Then call it like this

```
MyModel.trim_all
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use PHP for it ( in order to avoid sql errors, better print queries then execute them later ) :

```
$dbHost = 'localhost';
$dbUsername = 'root';
$dbPassword = '';
$dbName = 'database';
$db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
$db->set_charset("utf8");

$queries = '';
$query="SELECT * from table";
$result = $db->query($query);
$headers = $result->fetch_fields();
foreach($headers as $header) {
        $col = $header->name;

       $queries .= "UPDATE table SET `".$col."` = TRIM(`".$col."`) </br>";
}
echo $queries;
```

?>

Comment: It said the SQL queries not PHP Code sir.