# mysql trim column in database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, trim

```
UPDATE mytable SET mycolumn= LTRIM(RTRIM(mycolumn));
```

i use this to trim entire column from leading and trailing space,but what i want is

```
|ID|Name      |
|1 |demo 6    |
|2 |demo3 500 |
```

what i want is to trim NAME where last char is int by removing this int.

output

```
|ID|Name      |
|1 |demo      |
|2 |demo      |
```

is it doable with mysql alone ? or i will need to use php to update table ?

note: this table contain around 20K row

Edit:
ok php it is,

```
$s='';
foreach($q as $row){
$d=$row->name;
while(is_numeric(substr($d,-1))){$d=rtrim($d, '0123456789');}
if(is_numeric(substr($row->name,-1)))
$s.="update name_list set name='".$d."' where id='{$row->id}';\n";
}
echo "count:".count(explode('\n',$s))."<br/><pre>$s</pre>";
```

if i try to run them one by one it runout..

is there a better way to patch update rows?

Comment: proably quicker to do this in php, if this is a oneshot deal. you'd spend more time figuring out the sql-side string operations than it would do simply slurp that field into php and do `rtrim($field, '0123456789');`.

Comment: have you tried to SELECT INTO another table. BTW is this the same question as a year ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072197/mysqltrim-all-fields-in-database

Comment: @MarcB I agree that PHP is te way to go, but he might run in to trouble when the query takes to long to execute.

Comment: @Mr.Radical exactly, i have 8000 row to update now!, how can i do it on single query ? or i have to do it one by one ?

Comment: @Mr.Radical and nop its not :) check it out

Comment: @MomenMElZalabany I see that the problem is that you run out in other words it takes to long to execute. You could try to cut the operation into small pieces. E.g. where id between 1 and 50. That will still mean that you have to manually execute the query, but this is one time type of situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately MySQL currently (5.5) does not have a regular expression version of `REPLACE()`. Doing so in MySQL, while preferred and faster IMO, is not an option without a [UDF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-udf.html) or several nested calls to `REPLACE()`…

```
RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(..., '8', ''). '9', ''))
```

**Note:** the above will replace all digits. Not just those to the *right*. Leaving for future readers, but will not work in the case of the OP.

As such, PHP is your only option. Borrowed from **Marc B** :

```
// loop over all rows
$no_ending_digits = rtrim($field, '0123456789');
// update row
```

Comment: but replace() will trash ALL digits in the field. op just wants right-hand-side digits removed.