# Mysql: Trim all columns values when selecting

Tags: mysql

I need to select all columns of table:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
```

is there any way to trim all values without naming one by one like this ?

```
SELECT TRIM(*) FROM table_name
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mysql:Trim all fields in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072197/mysqltrim-all-fields-in-database)

Comment: @Toni that answer seems to update table each time a request is peformed. that i dont need that.

Comment: Why are you storing untrimmed data?

Comment: Anyway, you just have to name (and trim) each column, which is what you should be doing anyway.

Comment: @Strawberry I'm storing data through phpmyadmin. is there any function that trim data before storing automatically?

Comment: I don't use phpmyadmin, so I wouldn't know. I normally submit data to a database via a bit of application code (php, in my case), which will do all the tidying up.

Comment: ' I'm storing data through phpmyadmin' - doesn't mean much, are you using load data infile, importing using import wizard, inserting...

Comment: @P.Salmon I'm using insert